# ¿Cómo realizar operaciones con los resultados de dos consultas?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quisiera dividir esta consulta:

```
SELECT  'EGRESOS_UCI_ADULTO' AS INDICADORES, 
        COUNT(CONSULTA1.ESTANCIA1) AS RESULTADO 
FROM    ADNEGRESO
        INNER JOIN ADNINGRESO ON ADNEGRESO.ADNINGRESO = ADNINGRESO.OID
        INNER JOIN (
           SELECT  HPNESTANC.ADNINGRES AS ESTANCIA1, 
                   HPNESTANC.HPNDEFCAM  AS CAMA 
           FROM    HPNESTANC 
           WHERE   HPNDEFCAM IN (80,237, 238,239,240,241,242,243,244,
                                 245,247,248,249,245,247,248,249,250,
                                 251,252,253,254,255,256,257,256,357) 
           GROUP BY HPNESTANC.ADNINGRES, HPNESTANC.HPNDEFCAM
        ) AS CONSULTA1 ON CONSULTA1.ESTANCIA1 = ADNINGRESO.OID
        INNER JOIN HPNDEFCAM ON CONSULTA1.CAMA= HPNDEFCAM.OID
WHERE   ADNEGRESO.ADEFECSAL BETWEEN '01-01-2018' AND '31-01-2018'
```

con esta otra

```
SELECT  SUM((DATEDIFF(DAY,HPNESTANC.HESFECING,HPNESTANC.HESFECSAL)))  
FROM    HPNESTANC 
WHERE   HPNDEFCAM IN (80,237, 238,239,240,241,242,243,244,
                      245,247,248,249,245,247,248,249,250,251,
                      252,253,254,255,256,257,256,357) 
        AND HPNESTANC.HESFECING BETWEEN '01-01-2018' AND  '31-01-2018'
```

La primera consulta me arroja el numero de egresos en esa fecha, que son 83, y la segunda me arroja el numero de días de estancia del paciente en ese servicio, el cual me da 147.

Necesito dividir 147/83 que me da el promedio de días de estancia, ¿cómo hago para dividir esas consultas?

He intentado esto:

```
select b.sumavalor /a.resultado
(SELECT  'EGRESOS_UCI_ADULTO' AS INDICADORES ,COUNT(CONSULTA1.ESTANCIA1) AS RESULTADO FROM ADNEGRESO
INNER JOIN ADNINGRESO 
ON ADNEGRESO.ADNINGRESO = ADNINGRESO.OID
INNER JOIN
(SELECT  HPNESTANC.ADNINGRES AS ESTANCIA1, HPNESTANC.HPNDEFCAM  AS CAMA FROM HPNESTANC WHERE HPNDEFCAM IN(80,237, 238,239,240,241,242,243,244,
245,247,248,249,245,247,248,249,250,251,252,253,254,255,256,257,256,357) 
GROUP BY HPNESTANC.ADNINGRES, HPNESTANC.HPNDEFCAM) AS CONSULTA1
ON CONSULTA1.ESTANCIA1 = ADNINGRESO.OID
INNER JOIN HPNDEFCAM
ON CONSULTA1.CAMA= HPNDEFCAM.OID
WHERE ADNEGRESO.ADEFECSAL BETWEEN '01-01-2018' AND '31-01-2018')  a,
(
(SELECT  SUM((DATEDIFF(DAY,HPNESTANC.HESFECING,HPNESTANC.HESFECSAL))) as sumavalor FROM HPNESTANC WHERE HPNDEFCAM IN (80,237, 238,239,240,241,242,243,244,
245,247,248,249,245,247,248,249,250,251,252,253,254,255,256,257,256,357) AND HPNESTANC.HESFECING BETWEEN '01-01-2018' AND  '31-01-2018' )
)b
```

Comment: La primera consulta devuelve 2 valores, ¿cuál de los dos es el que quieres usar para operar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  'PROMEDIO' AS INDICADORES , SUM((DATEDIFF(DAY,HPNESTANC.HESFECING,HPNESTANC.HESFECSAL))) / COUNT(ADNEGRESO.ADEFECSAL) AS RESULTADO FROM ADNEGRESO
INNER JOIN ADNINGRESO 
ON ADNEGRESO.ADNINGRESO = ADNINGRESO.OID
INNER JOIN HPNESTANC
ON HPNESTANC.ADNINGRES = ADNINGRESO.OID
INNER JOIN HPNDEFCAM
ON HPNESTANC.HPNDEFCAM= HPNDEFCAM.OID
WHERE HPNESTANC.HESFECING BETWEEN '01-01-2018' AND  '31-01-2018'  AND HPNESTANC.HPNDEFCAM IN(80,237, 238,239,240,241,242,243,244,
245,247,248,249,245,247,248,249,250,251,252,253,254,255,256,257,256,357)
```

Listo, lo logré pero... ¿cómo hago para que el resultado se muestre en decimal?

Comment: A ver.. ninguna de las respuesta te sirvio? no publiques respuestas si no es la respuesta. Pedi aclaraciones en comentarios o aclara que cosas no te funcionan.

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que las dos consultas estan correctas, alcanza con meter los dos valores en otra consulta y dividir los valores:

```
Select a.valorconsulta1/b.valorconsulta2
FROM (la primera consulta) a,
(la segunda consulta) b
```

Siempre y cuando se supongan las siguientes cosas:

- Las dos consultas devuelven un solo registro.
- Las dos consultas devuelven una sola fila.

Porque funciona esto? porque el join que va a hacer es implicito, de todo lo que devuelve a (una sola cosa) con todo lo que devuelve b (una sola cosa).